# How to use a type array in map in c++

Tags: c++

I want to have something like dictionary and because of this matter I used map. I want the "key" be an int and "value" to be an array. To reach this, I did the following but I can not go further,

```
typedef std::string RelArr[2];
std::map<int,RelArr> mymap;
```

**Problem** I can not assign anything to "value"

```
mymap.insert(myintnumber,"ValueOfFirstIndex","ValueOfSecondIndex");
```

I receive this error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_InputIterator’ (‘int’ and ‘const char*’)
    - candidates are:
    - no matching function for call to ‘std::map<int, std::basic_string<char> [2]>::insert(int, const char [3], const char 
     [19])’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here, the first is that arrays can not be assigned to, only copied to, which makes them unusable to put in containers. Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
typedef std::array<std::string, 2> RelArr;
```

The second problem is regarding what the error actually tells you is that you're using the [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) function wrong, because there's no overload which takes two string literals.

If you want to insert an element in a `std::map` just do e.g.

```
mymap[myintnumber] = {{ "string1", "string2" }};
```

Or if you desperately want to use `insert`:

```
auto ret = mymap.insert(std::make_pair<int, RelArr>(
                            myothernumber, {{"hello", "world"}}));
if (ret.second == true)
    std::cout << "Insertion was okay\n";
else
    std::cout << "Insertion failed\n";
```

Comment: Am curious - why the double braces in `mymap[myintnumber] = {{ "string1", "string2" }};`?

Comment: @TonyD The outer pair for the `std::array` object, the inner pair for the actual array data.

Comment: does that do anything different to having a single pair?

Comment: @TonyD In reality no, not likely. But you might get a compiler warning about it.

Comment: I don't think that ("outer pair for the `std::array`") actually happens though... seems the assignment accepts an `initializer_list<>` (`a = il` in Table 103) which can be created with a single pair of braces, rather than ever creating a rhs `std::array` then doing a copy-construction.  On ideone it seems to work with one or two pairs of braces, but I'm not sure what the second pair do.  I'll keep an eye out for such warning in future.  Cheers.